# Display a value in a disabled textbox using TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to display a disabled textbox with the value 'FL' in it. Somehow the textbox does not have any value when it is displayed, but it is disabled. How do you display a value in a disabled textbox?

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { value="FL", disabled="disabled" }) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { disabled="disabled" });
```

is the code you need.

In the `model`, set the `State = 'FL'` & it should work correctly...

HTH.

Comment: How do you set "state" in the model?  Is it an attribute?

Comment: Model = ViewModel of the View which is set in the Controller action/method. This can be any type you want & in this case, the Model has a property called State which is being set to 'FL'

Answer (score 0):

You may write like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { @Value="FL", disabled="disabled" }) %>
```

"@" need, because value is a reserved world